# Show all users in Views that show Content only

Tags: views, users, nodes

I have created a view wherein it shows content.
But in my view, I wanted to show some contents and the list of the users(dropdown arrow for filtering)

My problem is that, the "USER:" is not available.How can I add user fields in my views that shows Content fields only?
Is there any module I can use for it to become possible?Thanks!

Comment: You can achieve it using views relationship where you need to relate content to user.
Link for views relationship and contextual filter:https://drupal.org/node/1841004

Comment: @AkshaySawant No, I dont want to show the contents created by a certain user. I will use it to expose the list of users then show their details.